# Is it useful to include a Facebook log in facility on an ecommerce website?

Tags: interaction-design, e-commerce, checkout

I'm in process of redesigning a website for my company, in cooperation with a digital agency. Our business is one of the leading companies in our country that sells consumer electronics (notebooks, PCs, smartphones, tablets, cameras etc.).

We are now working on designing the checkout process and are considering whether we should provide the ability for customers to log in with Facebook? Most of our products are not cheap.

What's your perspective on providing Facebook login on an ecommerce website? Do you have some hard data to support the argument one way or another?

Comment: "not cheap" but exclusive enough that one couldn't go elsewhere where they already have a login? I know using specifically the Google login, but sometimes the facebook login is enough to get me off the fence on an ecommerce site. (especially with Google's promise or whatever it's called)

Answer (score 2):

I think Facebook login (or any firm login) should not be mandatory. eCommerce is all about trust. Your users may trust your firm, but may not trust Facebook or others. Therefore, making firm's login mandatory may lead to a customers loss.

On the other hand, some users would appreciate not to have to fill once more the usual personal fields. In this view, using a largely used service may provide better efficiency when registering those users.

In the end, I would propose first a dedicated login form, with secondary third-party-based options. Also, when using a third-party service, I would inform the consumer in a simple manner which data I would gather from the external service. This precaution would indeed increase trust towards my ecommerce website.

Comment: Yes never make it mandatory to use a third party login, but an option just might reduce your bounce rate and increase your conversion...

Comment: I did not  mention about it - but yes, we provide dedicated firm login and we are thinking about Facebook just like an option. So it is possible to increase efficency with Facebook in that kind of business?

Comment: I guess so. Some users would be happy to find a faster and easier way to register (through Facebook or Google or ...). The others would not care about it as long as the dedicated solution is obvious.